# Hide the text of a button without changing the text using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-input

I am creating a memory game using Jquery where upon loading the page, a square grid of 16 buttons is visible with the values 1 to 8 randomly assigned to them, but these values are not visible to the user. Clicking on a block shows a letter or a number on the block. Only two blocks can show letters or numbers at a given time. I have seen many posts that hide or change the text of a button by changing the text (value) attribute of a button to "" (blank), but that doesn't work for me because I need to keep track of the value of the button and changing the value to "" does me no good.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Memory Game</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./hwk9.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./hwk9.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Memory Game</h1>
<form id="memory_game" method="post" action="">
  <table>
    <!--ROW 0-->
    <tr>
      <td><input id="b00" name="tile" type="button" value="1" onClick="return swap_tile(this.id)"/></td>
      <td><input id="b01" name="tile" type="button" value="2" onClick="return swap_tile(this.id)"/></td>
      <td><input id="b02" name="tile" type="button" value="3" onClick="return swap_tile(this.id)"/></td>
      <td><input id="b03" name="tile" type="button" value="4" onClick="return swap_tile(this.id)"/></td>
    </tr>
    <!--ROW 1-->
    <tr>
      <td><input id="b10" name="tile" type="button" value="5" onClick="return swap_tile(this.id)"/></td>
      <td><input id="b11" name="tile" type="button" value="6" onClick="return swap_tile(this.id)"/></td>
      <td><input id="b12" name="tile" type="button" value="7" onClick="return swap_tile(this.id)"/></td>
      <td><input id="b13" name="tile" type="button" value="8" onClick="return swap_tile(this.id)"/></td>
    </tr>
    <!--ROW 2-->
    <tr>
      <td><input id="b20" name="tile" type="button" value="9" onClick="return swap_tile(this.id)"/></td>
      <td><input id="b21" name="tile" type="button" value="10" onClick="return swap_tile(this.id)"/></td>
      <td><input id="b22" name="tile" type="button" value="11" onClick="return swap_tile(this.id)"/></td>
      <td><input id="b23" name="tile" type="button" value="12" onClick="return swap_tile(this.id)"/></td>
    </tr>
    <!--ROW 3-->
    <tr>
      <td><input id="b30" name="tile" type="button" value="13" onClick="return swap_tile(this.id)"/></td>
      <td><input id="b31" name="tile" type="button" value="14" onClick="return swap_tile(this.id)"/></td>
      <td><input id="b32" name="tile" type="button" value="15" onClick="swap_tile(this.id)"/></td>
      <td><input id="b33" name="tile" type="button" value="" onClick="return swap_tile(this.id)"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Javascript / Jquery

```
    // Call the shuffle function when entire page has been loaded
$(document).ready(function () 
{
  var combos = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"]
  var btns = document.getElementById("memory_game");
  combos = shuffle(combos)
  for (var i = 0 ; i <= 15 ; i ++)
  {
  btns[i].value = combos[i];
  }
  $("td").hide(3000);
});

/* Function that psuedo randomly shuffles the memory game board */
function shuffle(array)
{
  var currentIndex = array.length;
  var temporaryValue; 
  var randomIndex;

  // while there remain elements to shuffle
  while (currentIndex !== 0)
  {
    // Pick an element that remains
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;
    //Swap that element with the current element
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }
  return array;
}
```

Comment: You could save the values as an array of JS objects, similar to `{ value: 1, show: false }` in which the function determines whether the value is visible or not. Using a ternary operator, you could change the value of `show` each time a button is clicked `{ currentIndex.show ? false : true }` and appropriately show the value or hide it on the next line `{ currentIndex.show ? currentIndex.value : '' }`. Let me know if this points you in the right direction.

Comment: First of all it is not a good idea to store data in a View.

Comment: @yarix That's true of sensitive information, but for a simple game, it will suffice. There's no need to go storing it in a database or a .json file...you could utilize local storage, which would only add a few cycles to the process I outlined a little further up. In any case, the array could be printed to the console by anyone who knows how to access it no matter how it was stored.

Comment: Please add `swap_tile` function to question code.

Comment: just for reference, since you're using jquery already, you dont need all those "onclick" events inline. you could just do `$('.tile').on('click', function() { return swap_tile($(this).id()) });` in your js section

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To hide the text, set the text color using `rgba(0,0,0,0)` where the `a` stands for alpha, which we give a value of 0 (hidden).

To show the text, set the color to `''` which will remove the setting and return the text to its default color.

```js
var count = 0;
document.getElementById('demo').onclick = function(){
   this.style.color = ++count % 2 ? 'rgba(0,0,0,0)' : '';
}
```

```html
<button id="demo">This will disappear</button>
```

If you like jQuery you can use the following example instead.

```js
var count = 0;
$('#demo').click(function(){
   $(this).css('color', ++count % 2 ? 'rgba(0,0,0,0)' : '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="demo">This will disappear</button>
```

Comment: thank you @Tiny Giant. I actually did a variation of this using Jquery and got the results I desired. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Store the number in a `data-number` attribute. Then you can blank the text as you've tried, and then just query the `data` attribute.

HTML

```
<tr>
  <td><input id="b00" name="tile" type="button" data-number="1" value="1" onClick="return swap_tile(this.id)"/></td>
  <td><input id="b01" name="tile" type="button" data-number="2" value="2" onClick="return swap_tile(this.id)"/></td>
  <td><input id="b02" name="tile" type="button" data-number="3" value="3" onClick="return swap_tile(this.id)"/></td>
  <td><input id="b03" name="tile" type="button" data-number="4" value="4" onClick="return swap_tile(this.id)"/></td>
</tr>
```

JS

You would need to do a bit of refactoring, but this should give you an ideas as to how to achieve it...

```
$('input').on('click', function(){ // or whatever event you want
    var value = $(this).data('number'); // get the number
    // repopulate the text() with the value obtained
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A sneaky way of doing it is give the button a background color and setting the text color the same.

Ie

```
input{
   background-color: blue;
}
```

And use

```
$('#b20').css('color', 'blue');
```

Answer (score 0):

So, taking what @Tiny Giant said, this is the Jquery that I used to achieve the effect that I wanted.

```
    $(document).ready(function (){

      $("button").click(function() {

       $(this).css("color", "black");

      });
    });
```

My css file, when the webpage is loaded, changes the color of the button text to white and then by click on the button reveals the text color to black, like so:

```
  button {
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use button instead:

```
<button id="b33" value="15" onClick="return swap_tile(this.id)"><span>HIDE THE SPAN TEXT</span></button>
```

Hide the span inside the button:

```
$("#b33 span).hide();
```